# What type of brush is safe to use on hot pizzelle irons?

Tags: cleaning

When cooking [Pizzelles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizzelle) often the first one or two stick to the iron.  With so many intricate nooks and crannies in the iron it is challenging to clean before cooking more.  What types of tools are best to clean into the fine cracks when the iron is **hot**?

Comment: I don’t own a pizzelle iron, but in some Asian markets, you can find a scrubber that’s basically a bundle of sticks split from bamboo.  A really tight bundle won’t work, but a looser one will spread apart like a brush and might work

Answer (score 2):

I generally use a wooden toothpick.

I would suppose that any of the usual "basting brush" brush materials should be safe, though the silicone versions would "safe but useless."

You might also want to wait a bit longer on the initial heating to reduce the odds of the first ones sticking.

**IF** your pizzelle iron is **not** non-stick-coated, a metal "grill" brush might be OK, though it could also damage the seasoning. I don't know, mine *is* non-stick, so I would not think of putting a metal brush on it.